# Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-negative random variables with the same cdf, show the following inequality.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-negative random variables with the same cdf $F$. Show that, for any
$x \geq 0$

$$1 − 2F(x) ≤ P(X + Y > 2x) ≤ 2(1 − F(x))$$
My textbook also gave me a hint to compare to the inequality I've proved earlier
$$P(A) + P(B) − 1 ≤ P(A ∪ B) ≤ P(A) + P(B).$$
**Solution**

Since $X$ and $Y$ have same cdf
$$P(X>x)=P(Y>x)=1-F(x)$$
and $P(X >x,Y>x)\in[0,1].$

The problem I have now is to change $P(X + Y > 2x)$, I took some inspiration from earlier, but I'm not convinced that this equality is true
$$P(X + Y > 2x)=P(X>x)+P(Y >x)-P(X >x,Y>x).$$
Is this equality is accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\{X+Y>2z\} \subset  (\{X > z\} \cup \{Y > z\})$

and also $ \{X+Y \leq 2z\} \subset (\{ X\leq z\} \cup \{Y \leq z\}) $

So that:

$ 1 - 2F(z) = 1-(P(X\leq z) + P(Y\leq z)) \le 1-P(X+Y\leq 2z) $=

$= P(X+Y >2z)  \leq P(X>z) + P(Y>z) = 2(1-F(z))$

Comment: Those inclusions are due to X,Y,z being nonnegative

Answer (score 1):

It’s almost accurate. $\{X+Y>2x\}\subseteq \{X>x\}\cup\{Y>x\}$. To convince yourself of this, presume otherwise that $X,Y\leq x$ to derive a contradiction. Now apply $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.